# Meteor.js collection not being updated in startup function

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

Client side code:

```
Assignments = new Mongo.Collection("Tasks");

if(Meteor.isClient){
  angular.module('dolphin' ,['angular-meteor']);

  //Assignments controller
  angular.module('dolphin').controller('AssignmentLists' ,  function($scope){
   $scope.helpers({
     Tasks:() =>{
       return Assignments.find({});
     }
   });
  });
}
```

And the Server code is :

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.startup(function(){
    var tasks = [
      {
        'name':'Go for dinner today',
        'description':'Halloween Party'
      },
      {
        'name':'Plan to go to Salem',
        'description':'This is a good idea'
      }
    ];
    for(var i=0 ; i< tasks.length;i++){
      Assignments.insert(tasks[i]);
      console.log(tasks[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

The Assignments Collection is empty. When Meteor server is started ,the Assignments collection is not updated . The task details is suppose to be inserted into Assigments.
When Meteor.Mongo command is run in the terminal , the collection is just empty.

Can anyone throw some light on this topic how Meteor Collection must be updated during server startup?
Any help will be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: is your collection defined on both the client and the server?  It also looks like you're not publishing that data, or subscribing to it anywhere, but you could be using auto publish I suppose.

Comment: He said he can't see the data from the Meteor mongo console either, doubtful it's a pub-sub issue. More likely the insert code is not running. @cheral: do those `console.log()` statements log anything in your server console?

Comment: Could it be the order your files are being loaded in? I see you define `Assignments` in the top section, then reference it in the bottom section. If the two sections represent different files, check the top one is being loaded first and isn't inside a `client` folder

Comment: can you share a repo?  I don't see a reason it shouldn't work.  Also try to update to the new 1.3.1 version, there are a few fixes there